# Get all connected members of discord channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm working on a move command, which moves members with the role "Officer" into another channel. But I'm struggeling to get all members in the channel. The most logical solution would be:
[image]

When I `print(members)` I just get `[]` although I was connected to the channel.

I tried the `.keys()` solution too but i dont get the object back, but my ID in a dictionary. Then I tried get_member but the result is always None.

`guildG` is a global variable and set in `on_ready()` as follows:
[image]

My intents:

[image]

Comment: Have you passed the intents into your bot constructor?

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: can't see if you passed them into your bot constructor.

Comment: I didnt pass them... thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Added the intents to the bot constructor. Thats the trick :)

[image]